# Shiny - updateTabsetPanel - Change the selected tab on the client

Tags: r, shiny, tabs, shinydashboard

On home page of the app we have 2 valueBox. What I need is to make them clickable(work as button) and on click event jump to tabpanel.

What I need is to click on "Title1" valueBox on Home tab and it should redirect(navigate) the screen to "Summary" tabPanel on "Tab1" screen.

[image: Home]

[image: Tab1]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- navbarPage(
  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  title = "TabPanel",
  header = tagList(
    useShinydashboard()
  ),
  tabPanel(title = "Home",
           fluidRow(
             box(
               title = "ValuBox",
               width = 12,
               status = "info",
               solidHeader = T,
               valueBoxOutput("ibox"),
               valueBoxOutput("vbox")
             )
           )
  ),
  tabPanel(title = "Tab1",
           tabsetPanel(
             tabPanel("Plot"),
             tabPanel("Summary"),
             tabPanel("Table")
           )),
  tabPanel(title = "Tab2",
           tabsetPanel(
             tabPanel("BarChart"),
             tabPanel("SummaryTable"),
             tabPanel("TableDT")
           ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ibox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = "Title1",
      subtitle = "Text1",
      color = "aqua",
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  output$vbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = "Title2",
      subtitle = "Text2",
      color = "light-blue",
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT: I did not properly read your question. I've modified the code to fit your request about updating the inner tab of tab 1 to summary.*

In the `ui` object, you can wrap an output in a `actionLink` and then attach a observer to the link that updates the tab using `updateTabsetPanel`. However, first you need a `id` for the whole navbarPage. I've made necessary changes to your code so that by pressing the first valueBox, you are sent to the Tab1. I've added comments where i've added lines.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- navbarPage(
  id = "tabset", # NEW ID
  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  title = "TabPanel",
  header = tagList(
    useShinydashboard()
  ),
  tabPanel(title = "Home",
           fluidRow(
             box(
               title = "ValuBox",
               width = 12,
               status = "info",
               solidHeader = T,
               actionLink( #WRAPPED VALUEBOX IN ACTIONLINK
                 inputId = "link1",
                 label = HTML(
                   as.character(valueBoxOutput("ibox"))
                 )
                 
               ),
               valueBoxOutput("vbox")
             )
           )
  ),
  tabPanel(title = "Tab1",
           value = "tab1", #ADDED A VALUE PARAMETER HERE
           tabsetPanel(
             id = "tab1_inner", #ADDED ID HERE
             tabPanel("Plot"),
             tabPanel("Summary"),
             tabPanel("Table")
           )),
  tabPanel(title = "Tab2",
           value = "tab2", #ADDED A VALUE PARAMETER HERE
           tabsetPanel(
             id = "tab2_inner", #ADDED ID HERE
             tabPanel("BarChart"),
             tabPanel("SummaryTable"),
             tabPanel("TableDT")
           ))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$ibox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = "Title1",
      subtitle = "Text1",
      color = "aqua",
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  output$vbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      value = "Title2",
      subtitle = "Text2",
      color = "light-blue",
      icon = icon("credit-card")
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$link1, { #OBSERVER THAT CHANGES TAB WHEN LINK IS CLICKED
    updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "tabset", selected = "tab1")
    updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "tab1_inner", selected = "Summary")
  })
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```